# Is there a library for cache using an index or tags

Tags: php, model-view-controller, caching, tags, indexing

I'm working on implementing cache on the view level in a MVC application. The application is a custom php MVC + some zend libraries, but I think the question would apply to any MVC stack.

What I'd like to achieve is cache that invalidates partials/blocks but not entire pages.
The view consists of layouts and each layout can consist of blocks/partials and each partial itself can again consist of partials. Nothing out of the ordinary. Many of the partials use the same data, and if they data changes all should be invalidated. In the same way some partials use data from different models and should be invalidated if any of data changes.

What I'd like to achieve is a system where I would not have to go back to my model to change the code whenever a new partial or layout is created. My thinking was that it would be great if each cache items could somehow be "tagged" so when I'm in the data level I can simply invalidate all cache items using that tag. If I then create a new partial, I simply need to make sure I tag it with all the tags that are used within that cached block.

I could imagine that you would store a index in cache linking a tag with all related CacheId's.

Question 1: Does such a library exist? I'd hate to reinvent the wheel.
Question 2: OR is there a different "best practice" and is my reasoning flawed.

**Elaboration:**
Just came across this which is close to what I wan't to achieve, but in php
http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui

My question is how do I map cache keys to data so that when the data is updated I know which caches to invalidate? The cache key is set in the view, the clearing is done in the model (onSave, onDelete). How does the model know which caches it should remove?

For example:

The following is cached in the view, each generating a unique key for retrieval.

Partial 1:
     product x by user y = partial1/x.id-y.id
     product z by user y = partial1/z.id-y.id

And I use the same user again, but this time for comments

partial 2:
     Comment a by user y = partial2/a.id-y.id
     Comment b by user y = partial2/b.id-y.id

Now if I update user y, in the onSave I can not know all the cached partials dependant on y. I could, but I would have to retrieve all cache keys and test one by one if y is in them.

So my thought was, if I maintain a map which keys depend on y.id, I could easily clear cache without having to know what the keys are named. The view level fills the index, the model can use it to lookup the keys and invalidate those caches. So in the above example, after creating the cache I would have the following index:

```
x.id = [partial1/x.id-y.id]  
z.id = [partial1/z.id-y.id]  
a.id = [partial2/a.id-y.id]  
b.id = [partial2/b.id-y.id]  
y.id = [partial1/x.id-y.id, partial1/x.id-y.id, partial1/z.id-y.id, 
partial2/a.id-y.id, partial2/b.id-y.id]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you're going with the tags story, you might want to explain that somewhat further.

However, the partial caching can be done using server side includes (which can easily be handled by PHP): just use `<?include('cached/partial1.html')?>`, where `partial1.html` is a cached block of html data, generated from your back-end. That way you can store for example the text of an article, and you then update the html file when the article is edited.

Comment: I elaborated the question, hope this clears up what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest one 1 simple way to cache rendered pages to files, which may speed up Apache a lot coz Apache is ideal for static pages.

The caching mechanism is like this:

```
(1) No caching for POST requests

(2) Save all rendered pages for GET requests, save to files, eg. 
$Cache_File = "cache/".md5($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]).".html";

(3) Up on a new GET request, get the md5 of URI,
then check if file existing in cache, take it out and 
flush to browser.
```

Comment: This works for sites that are largely static, but if data keeps changing you would either have stale cache, or you would have to clear cache so often there would be little benefit. I've added a link to an example of what I want, it explains it best